# How to correctly initialize pool worker and run method

Tags: python, multiprocessing

**Background:**

I am trying to get a pool of workers going to solve a task. My issue is that I am trying to pass it a shared variable, but I get an error. I have written an initializer method for the workers that expect my variables, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import time
import multiprocessing

#initialize some multiprocessing stuff
num_processes = 8
y = multiprocessing.Array('d', 1000, lock=False)
new_y = multiprocessing.Array('d', 1000, lock=False)
dt = multiprocessing.Value('d',0, lock=False)
y_len = multiprocessing.Value('i',len(y), lock=False)
def init(y_to_share, new_y_to_share):
    global y, new_y
    y = y_to_share
    new_y = new_y_to_share


y[480:520] = [1] * 40

dt.value = 0.01

# our rule for reaction-diffusion

def advance():
    global y, new_y
    n = len(y)
    new_y = list(y)    
    for j in xrange(n):
        new_y[j] += dt * (20 * (y[j - 1] - 2 * y[j] + y[(j + 1) % n])
                               - y[j] * (1 - y[j]) * (0.3 - y[j]))
    y = new_y
    return y

# advance through t (t = i * dt) is at least 100; plot
# every 20

chunks = len(y)/num_processes
y_range = range(len(y))
y_range = [y_range[i:i+chunks] for i in range(0, len(y_range), chunks)]
p = multiprocessing.Pool(num_processes, initializer=init, initargs=(y, new_y))
i = 0
start = time.time()
while i * dt.value <= 100:
    if i * dt.value % 20 == 0:
        pyplot.plot(y, label='t = %g' % (i * dt.value))
    arr = p.map(advance, (y, new_y))#hand in an array of indices
    i += 1
    #print i * dt.value
end = time.time()

elapsed = end-start
print elapsed
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()
```

**Edit**: Post the actual error

**The error:**

```
runfile('/home/kevin/Downloads/cbb750_parallel_hw/propagating-signal-parallel.py', wdir='/home/kevin/Downloads/cbb750_parallel_hw')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-64-5ad3fdf93b59>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/kevin/Downloads/cbb750_parallel_hw/propagating-signal-parallel.py', wdir='/home/kevin/Downloads/cbb750_parallel_hw')

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 94, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/home/kevin/Downloads/cbb750_parallel_hw/propagating-signal-parallel.py", line 45, in <module>
    arr = p.map(advance, (y, new_y))#hand in an array of indices

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value

PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'multiprocessing.sharedctypes.c_double_Array_1000'>: attribute lookup multiprocessing.sharedctypes.c_double_Array_1000 failed
```

Can anyone help me solve this? I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I would like to use pool.map .

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Is it `TypeError: advance() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`?

Comment: @tdelaney its a PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'multiprocessing.sharedctypes.c_double_Array_1000'>: attribute lookup multiprocessing.sharedctypes.c_double_Array_1000 failed

Comment: @RobinNemeth I posted the error sorry bout that

Comment: You are trying to mix two different ways of passing data to a worker process - `Array` and the data passed in the `map`. Call. `p.map(advance, (y, new_y))` tries to call `advance` twice in two different processes. One gets `y` the other gets `new_y`.  But those are `Array` 's which are already shared with the child process via proxy objects.

Comment: How can I use map without passing in those 2 shared arrays?